# Bad HTML contact form redirecting to script.googleusercontent.com after submission

Tags: html, google-apps-script, contact-form

The following contact form http://wearedappr.com/contact.html send all informations to a google spreadsheet after submitting. However, it also redirects the user to https://script.googleusercontent.com (See image below)
[image: current redirection]

I am trying to have a confirmation message appearing instead of the redirection. Something like "Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you soon!" which would appear on the contact form page once we submit it instead.

Can someone help by any chance?

Here is form-submission-handler.js:
http://wearedappr.com/form-submission-handler.js

Comment: Can you share your HTML code.

Comment: I suspect you are submitting the form directly to Google. The best way to achieve what you want is by using Ajax to submit the form them parse the json response and present you confirmation message if successful

Comment: here is the HTML code view-source:http://wearedappr.com/contact.html

Comment: @ChukaOkoye, I have been trying to do what you described  but without any success. Do you know where I could find an example of this by any chance? 
Thank you

Comment: I will post an answer shortly. Give me a moment to get on my pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these.

1, Change your opening form tag to this:

```
<form class="gform pure-form pure-form-stacked" id="google_form_submit">
```

2, Add the following to your code before the closing body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#google_form_submit').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = $('#google_form_submit').serialize();
      $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzBvgWZZUgFbxCAlhPG4429wth61Rm7kymPaui3d5328UHHOiA/exec',
            data        : formData, 
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true
       }).done(function(data) {
            if(data.result == 'success') {
              // Form submission was successful and accepted by google. 
              // You can show your success message here

            } else {
               // Form was submission failed for some reasons.
               // You can examine the response from google to see whats missing

            }
       }).fail(function (jqXHR,status,err) {
            // Form submission failed due to some network or other errors
            // I am alerting the error but you can do anything else with it     
            alert(err);
       });
  });
</script>
```

Pardon my untidy codes... am posting the answer from a tablet.
If you see any thing wrong let me know so I can fix

Comment: Glad I could help